# Печать javascript

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, печать

Пишу небольшую программу, которая в конце должна отправлять кое-какие данные в печать. Так вот я печать сделала на JavaScript.

```
function printit(divName){ 
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Когда нажимаю на печать, выходит окно браузера для настроек печати. Хотелось бы обойтись без этого окна и предварительного просмотра страницы. Просто лишние кнопки еще нажимать, а у меня и так уже стоит кнопка печать, а потом еще одна, и для пользователей будет неудобно. Как бы избавиться от этого окна настроек? Помогите. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для пользователя будет неудобно, если он не сможет настроить параметры печати. Вдруг он хочет печатать на двух сторонах листа, или несколько страниц на одном листе, или он захочет изменить масштаб страницы перед печатью? Или вдруг вы спамер и желаете забросать пользователя кучей рекламы, распечатанной без его согласия? Именно поэтому браузеры не позволяют JavaScript'у принудительно начать печать без явного подтверждения пользователя. Всё, что вы можете сделать в данной ситуации - просто забить.

Comment: Ну ок, спасибо за ответ, только вот скажите, как делают печать, допустим, разные терминалы? Они же не запрашивают у пользователя настройки, когда, допустим, распечатывают всякие чеки и т.д.?

Comment: @lp_4eva, о каких терминалах идёт речь? Платёжные? Вы уверены, что там работает браузер? Причём в точности такой же, как на вашем компьютере, а не специально модифицированный под нужды терминала. Или, может, в терминале специальная версия ОС или драйвера принтера чеков. Или в браузере терминала установлено нативное расширение, обращающееся к драйверу принтера чеков в обход системной службы печати. Вариантов много, но вряд ли хоть один подойдёт для имплементации в обычном веб-приложении, которое будет запускаться на комптьютере обычного пользователя.

Comment: @lp_4eva, для терминалов два варианта:

1. Использовать спец. программы, а не просто браузеры.
2. Использовать исключительно Internet Explorer с ActiveX и настройками с отключенной безопасностью для подобных действий. Тогда хоть печатайте, хоть по желанию винты форматируйте)

Comment: fori1ton, Ого как все сложно, нет мне только для браузера))) Спец.программы я еще писать не умею:) 
Alex Krass, спасибо насчет Эксплорер я посмотрю, только все эксплорер использовать не будут :(

Comment: @lp_4eva, помимо того, что эксплорер использовать каждый не будет, да еще и не каждый использующий захочет снимать безопасность для активного содержимого. В данном случае проще смириться с этим неудобством, чем искать дополнительные трудности, затраты на которые себя не оправдывают.

Answer (score 2):

Данная функциональность реализована на уровне браузера, и ее нельзя отключить. Так что от этого окна print preview Вы никак не избавитесь, увы.

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение, для Google Chrome нужно в ярлыке поставить ключ `--kiosk-printing`.

После этого браузер будет печатать сразу без дополнительных настроек и выбора принтера.